# sqllite query match string and rank by best match

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to write a sql select query in sqlite, that performs a search for each word, ranks the highest match and displays it in rank desc order;

something like;

```
string = "hello world";
select notes, 
       if(notes like "%hello%', 1, 0) as r1, 
       if(notes like "%world%', 1, 0) as r2, 
       sum(r1,r2) as rank
from mytable
order by rank desc
```

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: See the [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case).

Comment: What is "ranks"? What is "the highest match"?